# Display variables as plain text in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails app I save some data as below.

```
def send_share_company(address, cid, from, council_id)

co = Council.find_by(id: council_id)
c = Company.find_by(id: cid)
@a = address.split(',')
@f = from
n = Notification.find_by(id: 'ad4e3718-0689-413b-8a52-96887e0d2aba')


 message =eval(n["body"])

 from = Email.new(email: 'noreply@my.network', name: "my Network")
 subject =  + cl["title"] + ' - Event of the Week: ' + c["name"]
 to = Email.new(email: a.to_s)
 content = Content.new(type: 'text/html', value: message)
 mail = Mail.new(from, subject, to, content)

 sg = SendGrid::API.new(api_key: ENV['SENDGRID_API_KEY'])
 pp sg.client.mail._("send").post(request_body: mail.to_json) unless Rails.env.staging?
end
```

I used another form to add message to the database. Then I retrieve it using,

```
n = Notification.find_by(id: 'ad4e3718-0689-413b-8a52-96887e0d2aba')
```

My message as below. This is the data which I have save in database.

> Hello,
>
> ## {@f} thought you should take a look at the company, #{c["name"]}.

When I display this in my app it displays as above. But I want display plain text.Is there way to do this?

Comment: What does Notification.find_by(id: 'ad4e3718-0689-413b-8a52-96887e0d2aba') return ?

Comment: @zawhtut it returns notification which I entered through form. That notification body include variables.

Comment: Looks like something needs to be wrapped in double quotes.  Can you tell the line exactly that creates this value, is it `content` from `content = Content.new(type: 'text/html', value: message)` ?  Can you also show  the code for where you are showing this?

Comment: what is the value of `n["body"]`, why using `eval`. Please share more info in order for us to help you as you didn't show us the most important value which is the value of the `message`

Comment: @tkhuynh I edited the question, I used eval to replace #{@f} and #{c["name"]} with the values.